# Inconsistent accessibility

Tags: c#

Hi I am a little new in programming in C#, and I am a little stuck. I have tried searching this site, but I have not been successful on finding an answer to my question. I have also tried changing my private to a public but that did not work.

Here is the error message I am getting:

> Error 2   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'exam2.location' is
>   less accessible than method
>   'exam2.Form1.MoveToANewLocation(exam2.location)'

Here is part of my code:

```
public Form1() 
{
   IntializeComponent(); 
   CreateObject(); 
   MoveToANewLocation(livingRoom); 
}

private void MoveToANewLocation(location newLocation) 
{ 
   currentLocation = newLocation;
   comboBox1.Items.Clear(); 

      for (int i = 0; i < currentLocation.Exits.Length; i++)  
         {
           comboBox1.Items.Add(currentLocation.Exits[i].Name);
           comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
         }
    textBox1.Text = currentLocation.Description;

       if (currentLocation is IHasExteriorDoor)
         {
           GoThroughTheDoor.Visible = true; 
         } 

       else 
         {
          GoThroughTheDoor.Visible = false; 
         } 
  } 


abstract class location
  {
      public location(string name)
        {
         this.name = name; 
         }

       public location[] Exits;
       private string name;
       public string Name
         {
           get { return name; }

          }

        public virtual string Description
           {
              get {
                     string description = "You're standing in the" + name + 
                     ". You see exits to the following places: ";  

                   for (int i = 0; i < Exits.Length; i++)
                       {
                         description += " " + Exits[i].Name;
                         if (i != Exits.Length - 1)
                         description += ","; 
                        }

                     description += ",";
                     return description; 
                     }

               }

       }
```

Comment: What is the location class marked as?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply I haven't been online since I have been going over the program. I have the location class marked as "abstract class location". In all the classes I made my code in public, when I do make them private I create a 'get' accessor so to be able to access the private code in another class. Thanks so much for responding

Answer (score 0):

Make location class public if it's not public already

Comment: This should really be a comment, we can't even see the class code yet. That being said, doing so would solve his problem (though this doesn't attempt to increase his understanding of access modifiers).

Comment: would you like me to edit my post and add more code to it? I didn't want to make the question really long by adding large chunks of code. If it will help others to answer the question better I can add more code

Comment: @user3617388 We appreciate not having the large chunks of code. However, we needed to see at least a piece of the "location" class code since it's accessibility modifiers were causing the error. Thanks for posting it!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try to make sure to put all the  needed code up the next time I ask a question. :) I made a few changes and my program is now working. I would post the answer, but I am not allowed to answer my own questions until 8 hours have passed since I am new user. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your class this way:

```
public abstract class location
{
   ...
}
```

As an aside, general code style has classes starting with a capital letter (ie. `Location`).

C# defaults the accessibility to `internal`, so having public methods inside the class will cause this error (like your constructor, properties, and virtual method). A good rule of thumb is to always declare classes public unless you know for sure you want everything in them to be internal or lower.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) for more information on access modifiers.

Comment: Thank you, I added the public and some other changes and my program is now working. I would post the answer, but because I am a new user it is making me wait 8 hours before posting the answer. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @user3617388 If this change solved your problem, you actually don't need to post anything. The concept of StackOverflow is that its a question/answer model. Your question was "Why am I getting an inconsistent accessibility error". Any other changes not related to that problem don't need to be part of an answer (although they technically could be). Feel free to accept the answer that helped you the most/was the most correct, it lets the community know what solved your problem and gives the answerer and you some reputation.

Comment: @user3617388, That being said, if you still feel like you have a significant answer to add to the question, go right ahead! Self-answered questions are encouraged here, but make sure that the answer is a SO-quality post and that you aren't just duplicating what has already been said.

Comment: thanks for the tip, as you know I am new to this website so I am still learning how everything works. I thought of posting the answer just so people would know the problem was figured out. However since the answer probably won't be that significant since everybody can't see the whole program, I may forgo the answer.